# How to make your speech recognition listen to you

Tags: c#, speech-recognition

Hi I am doing my undergraduate thesis using Michael C's speech Recognition program. I have created a command line in which BRIAN (name of the Synthesizer) will stop listening using this line of code:

```
case "Stop listening":
                BRIAN.SpeakAsync("Alright");
                _recognizer.RecognizeAsyncStop();
                _recognizer.UnloadAllGrammars();
                break;
```

This line of code works. However, when i say the command "start listening"i can't make him respond to my commands anymore. I need to create a case statement in which he can start to listen to my commands again.

Comment: Looks like you haven't read this nice article: [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I find it a little amusing that a program doing exactly what you ask it to do is perceived as a bug

Comment: I like this thesis nonetheless, sounds like fun :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is quite simple. Dont force your program to stop listening. Use a bool instead :

```
case "Stop listening":
    bAbleToListen = false; //stop listening
    break;
```

Then in your event handler u can do :

```
void _recognizer_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
{
  string speech = e.Result.Text;

  if (speech == "Start listening") {
      bAbleToListen = true; //resume listening
      BRIAN.SpeakAsync("I am online and ready");
  }
  if (!bAbleToListen) return;

  switch(...) {
     //your code
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect answer IMO, small note though in your second snippet you have `'Start listening'` which should use `"`

Comment: That is true, adjusted. Was stil in PHP mode

Comment: Is it possible to set it into "not listening" mode when I start the program? @DarkBee

Comment: Just init `BRIAN` and put the `bAbleToListen` to false after init